# Sharepoint Cognitive Search Skillset

Tags: sharepoint, azure-cognitive-search

I've managed to set up an indexer using a set of sharepoint documents as its data source through the REST API. I'm wondering, does anyone have experience with whether you can use the microsoft inbuilt skills or a custom ML skill with an indexer that has sharepoint as the documents behind the data source?

There's only one page of documentation, so i'm having a bit of trouble teasing out if my current problem with the skills not returning anything are an issue somewhere in the skillset definition, or because I can't deploy them on a sharepoint indexer. Does anyone else have experience of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible and fairly straightforward.

Documentation for creating the sharepoint (datasource) index is here: [Sharepoint Index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-index-sharepoint-online)

Skillsets apply as normal: [Create a skillset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-defining-skillset)